# Discord.py how to get slash command author id

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to get the user's id who uses slash command. I try use:

```
author = ctx.message.author.id
```

But i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

My full code:

```
slash = SlashCommand(Bot,sync_commands=True)

@slash.slash(
    name="getid",
    description="description",
    guild_ids=[guild id here]
)
async def _getid(ctx:SlashContext):
    author = ctx.message.author.id
    await ctx.send(author)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctx.author.id` should work. I don't think you can access the message from interactions.

You can use `interaction.user.id` for that if you use `discord.py`'s `app_commands`.

```
@bot.tree.command(name='userid', guild = discord.Object(id=...)) 
async def userid(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"The id of the user that invoked this command is {interaction.user.id}")
```

Comment: i get `AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Interaction'` error, and i edit my question and add my full code.

Comment: Oh, it seems you are using another package to handle slash commands and not `discord.py==2.0`. Anyway I think if you do `ctx.author.id`, it will work.

Comment: how i can install discord.py 2.0?

Comment: pip install discord.py

Comment: There are instructions on https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Answer (score 0):

Okay so slash commands don't have actual messages for the commands.
That's why when you try to do `ctx.message` it returns `None` because when you do `/getid`, and you send it, you dont actually send a message you send a command. And you get your error because `None` doesnt have an attribute `id`.

So what you need to do here is `ctx.author.id` because there is actually an author of the command but there is just no message. So you can directly go by `ctx.author.id`

Your new code should be:

```
slash = SlashCommand(Bot,sync_commands=True)

@slash.slash(name="getid", description="description", guild_ids=[guild id here])
async def _getid(ctx: SlashContext):
    author = ctx.author.id
    await ctx.send(author)
```